# batch loop in a range of numbers

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I want to do something in batch for loop in a range of numbers.

```
FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO command
```

This command is probably the one I need, but the "end" value is stored in a variable. I tried the following code, but results is not expected.

```
FOR /L %%X IN (1,1,%variable%) DO (
   call echo %%X
   set parameter=id=%%X
   echo %parameter%%
)
```

Results:

```
1
id=5
2
id=5
3
id=5
4
id=5
5
id=5
```

value of variable is 5, but why it always returns "id=5". What I expected is from "id=1" to "id=5

Comment: There is no need for `call` for `echo %%X`; and there is a `%` too much at the end of the line `echo %parameter%%`. Anyway, I am pretty sure the result is `ECHO is on.` for the very first time you run your script, is it not? You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) if you update a variable value inside of a code block in between `()` like a `for` loop...

Comment: This helped me figuring out that I need `/L` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo off
Set variable = 5

FOR /L %%X IN (1,1,%variable%) DO (
   set parameter=id=%%X
   echo !Parameter!
)
```

I think this does the trick.

Comment: Isn't this answer the same as the 1st question comment?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't an answer. This is an answer.

Comment: SO's purpose is not to have ten billion questions with just as many answers, meaning that not every question needs to be answered. Also taking info from someone's comment and write an answer is not a "best practice" (some might consider it _scavenging_).

Comment: @CristiFati - Using somebody else's comment as an answer is [perfectly acceptable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288847/what-to-do-when-my-comment-has-been-reposted-as-an-answer-by-another-user).

Comment: @SomethingDark Something that probably all of us already knew, but thank you for providing the __official__ statement. I don't have an "official" problem with this (hence no downvote from me), but I consider it more like an ethical one. As most of these situations arise from new users, I was trying to discourage this kind of behavior (at least to mention the source of the solution).